# iPhone 4 iTunes podcast list shows 3-4 words max?

Tags: itunes, iphone

I thought I would download a few podcasts with my iPhone.  I was sad to see that they all look like this:

- Some Person discusses ...
- Fulano Tal shows how ...
- How to fully setup a ...

How can I get a list that will wrap and show more than 3-4 words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest searching for podcasts on the iTunes web interface from within mobile Safari. Both Bing and Google accept a site parameter that will allow you to filter for a specific site. In thie case, you could search for a podcast and add the **site:itunes.apple.com** parameter at the end. Like this:

> this week in tech site:itunes.apple.com

The search results in Safari should be easier to read. Each link should open in the iTunes app in your iPhone. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. The iPhone screen is just to small. I am using the Mac to search for podcasts.

Maybe some of the third party apps could help.